# Slide transition delay in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, presentation

just finished recording a 3-minute PowerPoint presentation, exported it, and created a video. However, in the video, after I finish presenting 1 slide, there is like a good 15 seconds of dead silence with nothing happening before it moves on to the next slide. Any way I can fix this delay?

Comment: Are you screen-recording or exporting it by saving it as .MP4?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.